# An equivariant social choice in Mathematical economics

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, economics

Motivated by [this paper and its  economics motivations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086904800161), we recall that a social choice among $n$ objects is  a  continuous function $$f:\overbrace{M\times M\times\cdots\times M}^{\text{$n$ times}}\to  M$$

which satisfy the following conditions:

1) $f(x,x,\ldots,x)=x$

2) $f$ is unchanged  under all permutations  $\sigma \in S_{n},$ [the symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $n$ elements.

Perhaps the following could be  considered as a social model for the above mathematical problem.

A  client has to choose one item among $n$ items $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$. His preference  function is denoted by the above $f$.

Now it is  natural that we assume that  the client faces with n different items, so $x_{i} \neq x_{j}$, $\forall i \neq j$. So we  consider [the ordered  configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space) $$F_{n}(M)=\{(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})\in M^{n}\mid x_{i} \neq x_{j},\;\forall i \neq j\}  $$.

There is  an obvious  action of the  symmetric  group $S_{n}$ on $F_{n}(M)$.

Now the following question can be counted as an  equivariant analogy of the  social choice problem:

> Assume that $M$ is  a manifold  which is acted  by the  symmetric  group $S_{n}$. Is there always an equivariant continuous  map $f:F_{n}(M)\to M$? If not, for  what type of  manifolds the answer is  affirmative? What type of algebraic topological obstructions would appear?
>
> Can we find  an economics interpretation for this equivariant version?

**Example:** For $M=S^{1},\; n=2$, the  symmetric  group $S_{2}$ can act  on $S^{1}$  by complex conjugation $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ Then the function $f(z,w)=z\bar{w}$ satisfies $f(z,w)=\overline{f(w,z)}$.

In this example let's replace the conjugate action by antipodal action. Then $f(z,w)= (z-w)/|z-w|$ is  a  map $f:F_{2}(S^{1})\to S^{1}$  which satisfy $f(z,w)=-f(w,z)$?

Comment: In your first display, $M$ is the set whose elements are the $n$ objects?

Comment: I do not understand the bit about a client "choosing one item among $n$ items".  Are you saying that for every $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ there exists an $i$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$ ?

Comment: I think Ali must have gotten the following standard model a bit twisted? $M$ is a space of possible preferences, and there are $n$ agents each of whom, $i$, has a preference $x_i \in M$. A social choice function $f: M^n \to M$ maps $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to a single group preference $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in M$. Condition (1) is unanimity (if everyone prefers $x$, the group chooses $x$) and condition (2) is anonymity (rearranging the agents' names doesn't matter). But I don't see how to reconcile this with the client-item story or the ordered configuration space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Prof. Myerson  No, F_n(M) is the set of n ordered objects where objects are in M.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Very interesting point. Such assumption is not  included in no modeling of "Social choice", neither in Eckmann paper, nor other references.

Comment: @usul  Thank you for your  comment. I think the philosophy of  Math  modeling is a bit complicated. In this particular case, the social choice, the comment of Landsburg is  important.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I asked a yes-or-no question.  "Very interesting point" is not an answer to a yes-or-no question.  Then you say "Such assumption is not included....", but you've left unedited the part where you appear to have made this assumption.  So I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: ...any way my modeling is based on the following story: A client enters a shopping center consisting of $n$ different brands(WITH  DIFFERENT PRODUCTS). He/She would be offered to choose  $x_{i}$ from the $i-th$ brands, however she/he is not  obligated to apply the offers. Perhaps the ordering can have some social justification.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg  No  I am not saying that there is  an $i$ with that property. But I think your question is very interesting. Because if the modeling is a real modeling, the preference function must satisfy the condition you mentioned, that is there is a $i$  with $f((x_[1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}))=x_{i}$

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  I don't know what a "real modeling" means.  I don't know of any literature that makes the assumption you''re making, and I can't think of any reason why it should.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg  By real modeling I mean a modeling which is  constructed based on the real social situations, not  just a pure  mathematical  construction without real application to the real social situation. By this definition, I would like to know whether you count the social choice modeling, as described in various  papers and I introduced in the first lines of my question  , as a real modeling?

Comment: I would deny that the original topological social choice problem has a sensible economic motivation, "homotopic to a dictatorial rule" is a fairly useless concept.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker:  If "the original topological social choice problem" means the first several lines of the post, before it goes off the rails at "a client has to choose....", then I don't understand what you're objecting to.  The formulation of the problem contains nothing remotely similar to the phrase (or concept) "homotopic to a dictatorial rule".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker:   Suppose $n=2$, $M$ is the positive real numbers, $x$ is the amount I'd like our government to spend on mathematical research and $y$ is the amount you'd like our government to spend on mathematical research. Then it seems entirely reasonable to hope that the amount $f(x,y)$ that the government actually spends is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$.  Once you admit that continuity is a reasonable requirement, you are forced to consider the topology on $M$.  That seems like a pretty sensible motivation.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg The "homotopic to dictatorial rule"-formulation is the one Chichilnisky originally used when she started that literature within social choice theory. The issue is not emphasized in the article cited by her though, so I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: In view of the fact that you've completely ignored my comment, please remove the edit saying you've responded to it.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg   Prof.  Landsburg  My  apology if  I did not  understand your  comment, completely.I  would  appreciate if you  say me what is unclear. I tried to replace  the classical  notion of  social  choice  by  a  new one: My suggestion is the  following: A  continuous  map from configuration space to the  ambient space which is equivariant(With respect to the obvious action of the symmetric group on the configuration space and a given action on M

Comment: By "Very interesting point" as a response to your  first comment I  mean: "If the classical notion of the social choice is very natural, then any such f should satisfies the condition you mentioned in your first comment.

Comment: But it is not the case, any such f can not satisfy that  condition.

Comment: No, my point was certainly not that any natural notion of social choice should satisfy that condition.  (Let's call it the "Taghavi condition").  My point was that a) in the first part of your post, you seem not to be assuming the Taghavi condition, b) In the part beginning "Perhaps the following..." you suddenly seem to be assuming it, c) It is in any event a completely unnatural condition to impose, but d) you're still free to impose it if you want to, but e) the important thing is to __stop contradicting yourself__ and tell us whether you're assuming it or not.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg  Thank you  very much  for your explanation:  I realize what are you saying.  At the first part of the post I just  recall the classical notion of  social choice IN THE  MATHEMATICAL   language. By "Perhaps the following.."I tried to give a personal understanding of the economics interpretations of this classical math notion. Then I tried to show that this interpretation is more natural provided we remove repeated points that is x_{i}=x_{j}. This leads me to the new formulation in terms of configuration space.  But can I ask you why do you think the condition is unnatural?

Comment: Could I remove and remedy some unclear points of my post?

Comment: Dear @AliTaghavi, what is unclear to me is why the manifold of preferences  $M$ should come with an action of the symmetric group?

Comment: The condition is unnatural because social choice is supposed to model __compromise__, and the condition rules out all compromises by fiat.  If I want the new bus station built in my backyard, and you want the new bus station built in your backyard, why would we want to force the social planner to choose one of those options without allowing him to build the new bus station, say, somewhere half way in between?

Comment: Or:  If all Trump supporters and all Clinton supporters can unanimously agree that Todd Trimble is their second choice, why should the planner be forbidden by assumption from adopting a  mechanism that makes Todd Trimble the winner?   (In this case $M$ is the set of orderings of the candidates.)

Comment: @MarkGrant: "What's unclear to me is why the manifold of preferences $M$ should come with an action of the symmetric group".  What's even more unclear is why that symmetric group should just happen to be of the same size as the number of voters.  If a new voter is born, do the relevant symmetries of $M$ suddenly change?

Comment: @MarkGrant  Do you mean : what is the social justification for this group action on M?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @MarkGrant  To be honest, my motivation was Client-brand systems  not Voter -preference system. So the different  brands gives different goods. This is why I excluded repeated point to have the  configuration space.After all I asked the same question in the post: what is the social justification for the group action?

Comment: @MarkGrant  Any way I confess that I did not present necessary social motivation for such consideration.

Comment: But I have  some  questions  about the naturality of the classical  social choice. If it would be a natural modeling of the voter-preference, so any such f should  NOT be  defined on the  configuration space! because  the result of a selection is  meaning less if  all people chose different preference. Moreover what is the justification of  manifold  consideration? Is not  more natural to consider  a  discrete preference space?

Comment: @MarkGrant            After all I am interested in the variety of  social choice: I explain:  We say that two social choice f and  g are  similar if there  is  a  homeomorphism $\phi$  on $M\times M\times  \ldots \times M$  such that $f=g\circ \phi$. This  socially says that the two selection have  same  nature.  Questions: Are there two real  analytic  social choice on $\mathbb{R}$ which are not  similar(Lets we have two voter)

Comment: As another question: Is there  a  social choice  on $\mathbb{R}$, as preference  manifold, with two voters  such that f is  smooth without  singularity but the  corresponding  level sets(foliation)  is  not  topological equivalent  to the social choice corresponding to the natural mean $x+y/2$?

Comment: And finally I think the following question is  natural: Assume that M is  a  manifold such that it admits a n-social choice for every n, is it true to say that for every n there is  a  social choice with the following stronger condition: $f(\overbrace{x_{1},x_{1},x_{1},\ldots,x_{1}}^{k-times},x_{2},x_{3},\ldots, x_{n-k})=x_{1} $  if $k > [n/2]$? This  is  natural expectation from a fair choice. The answer is affirmative  for $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Regarding the assumption that $M$ is a manifold: That depends on the context. For voters in an election, for example, there is usually a finite number of preferences. But it is easy to imagine situations where the set of preferences naturally form a metric space, or even a manifold (as in Steven Landsburg's explanation regarding govt spending on Maths above).

Comment: Or if you want a more interesting manifold---suppose a circular beach surrounds a lake and the govt is deciding where on that beach to erect a lifeguard station.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll attempt an answer to the mathematical question, without discussing the motivation. As I understand it, $M$ is a manifold with $S_n$-action, and we are asking whether there exists an $S_n$-equivariant map $f:F_n(M)\to M$, where the action on $F_n(M)$ is by permutation of coordinates (and in particular has nothing to do with the action on $M$).

As a first observation, note that if $x\in M$ is a fixed point $x$, then such an $f$ exists; just map everything to $x$.

A general necessary condition for the existence of a $G$-map $f:X\to Y$ between $G$-spaces is given by the *Faddell-Husseini index*, as decribed for example in this paper:

> Pavle V. M. Blagojević, Wolfgang Lück, Günter M. Ziegler, *Equivariant Topology of Configuration Spaces*, J. Topology **8** (2015) pp 377–413, doi:[10.1112/jtopol/jtu029](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtu029), arXiv:[1207.2852](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2852).

Given a $G$-space $X$ and a commutative ring $R$, the Faddell-Husseini index of $X$ is the ideal in $H^*(BG;R)$ defined by
$$
\operatorname{Index}_G(X;R):=\ker(p^*:H^*(BG;R)\to H^*(EG\times_G X;R)),
$$
where $p:EG\times_G X\to BG$ is the projection of the Borel fibration. Then it is easy to see that if there exists a $G$ map $f:X\to Y$ then 
$$
\operatorname{Index}_G(Y;R)\subseteq \operatorname{Index}_G(X;R)
$$
must hold. You can sometimes rule out existence of equivariant maps using this property. The index of the configuration space $F_n(M)$ is probably difficult to compute in general, but is done in the linked paper for $M=\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very interesting answer and very  helpful link.

Comment: It seems that the link no longer works. Here is [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2852) and pdf on the [author's website](https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/data/1207.2852v3.pdf).